# Inside a Django model class, is it possible to asssign an attribute with the value of another attribute's foreign key?

Tags: python, django

```
class Post(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    post_by = models.TextField(max_length=50)
#   value=
```

With the above django model, is it possible to assign to value such that I get item's foreign key object called Item and then with that I get Item's id and this is stored in the attribute value?

Comment: I don't understand why wouldn't you access it by something like `Post.Item.Attribute` or `post__item__attribute`. Is there any reason not to?

Answer (score 0):

In django you already have the `id` in the `item_id` attribute of the model Post.

Comment: If you look closely at my code, item takes as a foreign key another object called Item (capital "I", my bad).